# Adding a new IronPython WPF Window to complains "Window is not supported in a WPF project"

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, ironpython

Immediately after adding a brand new, untouched WPF window to my IronPython 2.7 project in VS2013 (with Python Tools for VS 2.0.11016), it tells me "Invalid Markup" in the design window, and the error list shows:

> Window is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.
>
> Grid is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.

The XAML window has this innocuous looking code in it:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Does Python tools for VS not really support form creation?  Did I forget to configure something?

Comment: does it compile? are all needed references for WPF added?

Answer (score 14):

The project was started as an "IronPython Windows Forms Application" rather than an "IronPython WPF Application" so it was missing the relevant references:

- PresentationCore
- PresentationFramework
- WindowsBase

Adding them makes WPF forms functional, or just recreating the project.

<sub>If all of those references appear to be in the project, removing/readding some *might* help. Another user reported he had to do so for 'PresentationFramework'; perhaps there's a couple that have the same name?</sub>

Comment: For me, I had to check the boxes next to them in "add references"; didn't had to delete them.

Comment: For me, removing "PresentationFramework" from References and adding it back solved the problem.